# Issue Exporting database query results to Excel

Tags: php

I need to export the results of a MySQL query to an Excel file. I picked up some code to achieve this, but there is one issue. The code sends the header information to the browser with the .xls content type and the query results following the headers. The code for the called page is as follows:

```
<?php
function cleanData(&$str)
{
$str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
$str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

// filename for download
$filename = "customer_inventory_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

$flag = false;
$query = "SELECT customer_id,sku,qtyoh,date FROM sims_customer_inventory WHERE   customer_id=$customer_id and date=(select max(date) from sims_customer_inventory)";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
while(false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
if(!$flag) {
  // display field/column names as first row
  echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
  $flag = true;
}
array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
?>
```

The problem is that when the page is called in this form:

```
<form action="inventory_download.php" method="get" onsubmit="return validateInventoryform();">
```

The file does not automatically download. However, when I refresh the page the file downloads. My problem is that when the page is called this should automatically execute the code to download the file. It does not do that. I have looked all over the internet to solve the problem, but I can't find out why it does not work.

Comment: don't know where you picked that up, but naming the file .xls does not make it an excel file. may as well name it sex.mp4 and see it it magically turns in to a porn video. this is the libary i use to make valid excel files: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: .. if you don't need any formatting why not just create a csv, which is compatable with excel and a lot of other applications

Comment: The user specifically wants a .xls file. The code does work it just does not send the header information until the page is refreshed. That is the part I can't figure out.

Comment: 'does work" well it is most certainly does NOT create a valid excel file, if that's your definition of work ...

Comment: ok, semantics. It does not create a file: true. It does download data that opens in Excel. That is close enough. The problem is that it does not do it automatically as it should. I will try phpexcel. I am sure that will work.

Comment: its not semantics at all. one is a valid excel file one is a text tile named as *.xls that your version of excel on your machine just happens to be interpreting correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I think that phpexcel is the way that I need to go. It sounds like a more stable approach.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the passing of ajax data to the external page that creates the .xls data. The answer is to turn off the ajax data in the link:

```
<a href="something.php" data-ajax="false">
```

That will allow the php code to work properly. There is still the problem that this is not actually a valid Excel file. This code creates a header and follows it with data that is interpreted as an Excel file. It is not an Excel file, but it does open in Excel and then it can be saved as an Excel file. That is an important distinction. If you are in need of an actual Excel file then [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is what you should use. That is probably the best option.